# Calling JSP files gives a NoSuchMethodError when app deployed outside of Eclipse

Tags: java, jsp, maven, servlets, web-applications

I have a maven project that works completely as intended inside of eclipse. It also builds and runs outside of eclipse, but when I try to call the frontend (JSP web pages) then I get the following:

> Problem accessing /. Reason:
>
> ```
> javax.servlet.ServletContext.getJspConfigDescriptor()Ljavax/servlet/descriptor/JspConfigDescriptor;
> ```
>
> ### **Caused by:**
>
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.servlet.ServletContext.getJspConfigDescriptor()Ljavax/servlet/descriptor/JspConfigDescriptor;
>   ...

I've looked around and it seems that this message is associated with an incompatibility between Servlet 2.5 and Servlet 3.0. But I already have Servlet 3.0 as a dependency in my pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

So I can't figure out why this dependency that I need isn't being included when I build and deploy outside of eclipse even though the build itself is successful.

Any idea what could be causing this and how to fix it?

EDIT:
The JSP access isn't configured in web.xml. The index.jsp file is the welcome file set for the  jetty server with this snippet:

```
// configure webapp
WebAppContext webroot = new WebAppContext();
webroot.setResourceBase("src/main/webapp");
webroot.setContextPath("/");
webroot.setWelcomeFiles(new String[] {"index.jsp"});
webroot.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
server.setHandler(webroot);
```

The remaining few jsp files are in the webapp folder.

EDIT 2:
I've examined the contents of the jar created when packaging my project and it appears that there are multiple copies of the javax/servlet/Servlet.class in the jar. This is a bit perplexing. I'm assuming that these other dependencies (listed below) that I have in my pom must be adding the additional Servlet.class files.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
  <version>8.1.8.v20121106</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
  <version>8.1.8.v20121106</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-jsp</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.8.v20121106</version>
</dependency>
```

But I'm not sure how to fix any of this...

If anyone has any ideas, I'd love to hear them. The only real constraints that I have is that I have to use jetty 8.1.8.v20121106.

Comment: Are you deploying this in Tomcat 6 or Tomcat 7?

Comment: this application has embedded Jetty

Comment: Which version of embedded jetty?

Comment: can you show your `web.xml`?

Comment: not using web.xml for accessing the JSPs. I've Edited the question with additional details

Comment: If you don't mind you could update a sample of your project to dropbox and I could look at it...

Comment: thanks for the offer meewoK, but I'm not able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you might be deploying a servlet 3.0 on tomcat 6 which is not supported and would cause this exception.

An additional possibility is that your exporting additional .classes within your war that are interfering with tomcat's default libraries.

Comment: I'm using embedded Jetty 8. But even in your explanation... I'm curious why would it work in the Eclipse environment?

Comment: Because if your web-server (tomcat or jetty) does not support 3.0 servlets it would cause that exception as the specific classes/methods are not available.

Comment: Running the program inside of eclipse is using the same embedded jetty correct?

Comment: Are you using eclipse SE or eclipse EE? Do you have tomcat or jetty servers configured in your eclipse EE? Is your project executed from public static void main? If your executing from main, then maybe when you run out of eclipse your not configuring your classpath correctly, or your JAR is not including dependent libraries which would cause the class deffinition not found. Basically, if your whole project in eclipse is an SE project, most likely it is a classpath issue. If it is a WEB PROJECT with eclipse EE having servers configured etc it is another issue.

Comment: The project was not configured as an eclipse EE web project, so I'll assume you'd call it an SE project as the only EE component I'm really using is javax.servlet. I don't have any servers configured in eclipse. Yes, the project is executed from public static void main. So from your response it would seem that this is a classpath issue... which is strange that it would only miss this dependency as they are all added the same way (through maven).

Comment: So, you added your libaries to the project and everything runs fine. Try making your JAR and including all referenced libaries (Export Runnable Jar File and Extract or Package required libraries). See: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGf8iiNBUjY

Comment: yes, the project already creates a runnable jar... I'll check the contents of the jar for the correct version of javax.servlet

Comment: Ok, I looked in the jar and I have 4 copies of javax/servlet/ServletContext.class! I'm guessing this is because